# preg_match to fetch number 2 after 1 instead of 10

Tags: php, preg-match

I am having some files in a folder as follows:
`ss1.txt, ss2.txt, .., ss9.txt, ss10.txt, ss11.txt, .., ss19.txt, ss20.txt`.

When I tried to fetch these files using preg_match, I got the result in the order:

`ss1.txt, ss10.txt, ss11.txt, ... ss19.txt, ss2.txt, ss20.txt`.

What I need exactly is as follows:

`ss1.txt, ss2.txt, .., ss9.txt, ss10.txt, ss11.txt, .., ss19.txt, ss20.txt`.

The expression that I am using is as below:

```
    '/_ss[1-9]+\.txt/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a list of the first 0-9 matches first:

```
<?php
$files = array("ss1.txt", "ss2.txt", "ss14.txt");
$sorted = array();
$a_string = "";
foreach ($files as &$file) {
    preg_match ('/_ss[1-9]\.txt/', file, matches)
    $a_string = $matches[0];
    if (isset($a_string)) {
       array_push($sorted, $a_string); } }
unset($file);
```

Then build the second list of 11-20 matches:

```
foreach ($files as &$file) {
    preg_match ('/_ss[0-9][0-9]\.txt/', file, matches)
    $a_string = $matches[0];
    if (isset($a_string)) {
       array_push($sorted, $a_string); } }
unset($file); 
?>
```

Another way could be to use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to return two lists of matches without looping, but only if your data is already in one big string (or you want to convert it).

```
$giant_text = join (" ", $files)
$list_of_single_dig = preg_match_all('/_ss\d\.txt/', $giant_text, $matches);
$list_of_double_dig = preg_match_all('/_ss\d\d\.txt/', $giant_text, $matches);
$sorted = array_merge ($list_of_single_dig, $list_of_double_dig)
```

Comment: What about `ss10.txt` or `ss20.txt`?

Comment: There should be no issue with that. We matched all the single digits first, so all that's left are 10 through 20, which as he shows in the question get inserted in the correct order.

Comment: The regex `[1-9][1-9]` will not match `10`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

```
$sorted = natsort($unsorted_files);
```